# "Загрузить еще" в WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Есть сайт, с которого берутся данные и отображаются на экране. Загрузка делится на 2 этапа:

1. Получить "короткие" данные со страницы (заголовок, автора, описание, ссылку, id).
2. Отправить запрос на конкретный объект, получив оттуда оставшиеся данные (полное описание, комментарии и др.).

Можно привести пример с тем же SO, где на главной странице мы видим только часть вопроса, а на самой странице вопроса видим весь текст и комментарии.

На данный момент, я беру все объекты со страницы, отображаю то, что есть, а после отображения запускаю некий фоновый `Task`, который грузит **все** объекты этой страницы, отправляя порядком 40 запросов на сервер с некой задержкой. Но это ведь неправильно, ибо зачем грузить все данные со страницы, если на экране постоянно элементов 10?

Собственно вопрос: Как при прокрутке элементов в том же `ListBox`, отправлять запрос на сервер **только для видимых объектов**? Ну а при выходе за пределы видимости, отменять этот запрос (если есть).

Конечный вариант, который хотелось бы, либо нечто подобное (видели небось много раз в Web, мобилках):

[image: Result]
<sub>(источник: [telerik.com](https://docs.telerik.com/blazor-ui/components/grid/images/virtual-scrolling-overview.gif))</sub>

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132773/discussion-on-question-by-evgeniyz----wpf).

Comment: Интересно, чем история закончилась, было бы полезно узнать, куда копать.

Comment: @aepot Мне не нравилось то, что получалось, не было скажем так, стабильности, универсальности, проект лагал при отладке, гадил сильно в лог, некоторые контролы ломали вообще весь механизм. В тот момент я забил вовсе на эту затею. Так что, если есть хорошее решение, буду рад его увидеть, будет полезно на будущее, ну а пока, страницы наше все)

Comment: Я бы мог этим заняться, но увы, после проблем с с#, я с ним перестал дружить , пересел на си :)

Comment: @ori - и много приложений с гуем написали на си?

Comment: @ori SO это вроде не фриланс, а сайт, где сообщество делится друг с другом знаниями, собирая полезное в одном месте. Поэтому "мог этим заняться" - есть желание и силы, дерзайте, будет многим думаю полезно, ну а нет, смысл тогда от этого комментария, мне немного не понятно...

Comment: Кстати, буквально на днях начал осваивать WinUI3, и там в пакете Community Toolkit есть решение данного вопроса, зовется [IncrementalLoadingCollection](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/WindowsCommunityToolkitDocs/blob/main/docs/helpers/IncrementalLoadingCollection.md), это коллекция, которая автоматически вызывает логику получение нового куска данных, если скрол дошел до конца. Коллекция знает, есть-ли еще объекты в ней, а также знает идет в данный момент загрузка данных, а на основе этого можно уже прокрутить всякие анимации и прочее. Правда это UWP/WinUI3, в WPF вопрос все еще открыт